# Travelling to Berlin without a bank statement

Tags: schengen, legal, dubai, western-europe, schengen-visas

My brother won a trip for two to Berlin, Germany. We are a Philippine Passport holder, but we are currently living now in Dubai. And the German Embassy is asking for a bank statement. My brother has bank statement. However, me as the sister doesn't have bank statement. My company didn't provide us a bank account for salary since we're not a big company. We only have few employee, not even 15. I received my salary CASH. the only documents i dont have is Bank Statement. Is salary slip is fine for me to be eligible for schenegen visa?

He has all the requirements needed including bank statement, but I only have a salary statement.

**Is that enough for me to get a schengen visa?**

The company will provide the ticket, hotels and transportation.

Comment: At the very least, you'll need to state your nationality. You'll probably need to give more information as well, but I'll leave it to somebody who might actually be able to answer your question.

Comment: Why don't you contact the embassy and tell them about your situation?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, your brother may write a letter that he's going to provide for you and your sister during the trip, and that, together with his bank statement, ought to be enough. If he can show enough money in his bank statement, of course.

You can clarify this with the embassy.

This assumes that you're going to travel as a group.